# Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to have code/project/folder structure mapped from TFS to mutiple machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, shared, workspace

I am currently working on several applications and in n some of these apps the solutions contain projects from multiple work spaces in Visual Studio 2010.

This causes an issue when others attempt to work on the code for a certain application or simply download the code and run the app. I have my work spaces for my computer defined, but others do not.

What I want to do is have a way to set up a work space or sort of work space template where anyone can download the code from the server, while on any machine and with the required folder structure, and the application will run.

For instance, if I had the following server structure:

```
$/
  $/SolutionFiles/

  $/SubFolder1/
    $/SubFolder1/ProjectA/
    $/SubFolder1/ProjectB/

  $/SubFolder2/
    $/SubFolder2/Project1/
    $/SubFolder2/Project2/
```

...and I had a solution `$/SolutionFiles/MyAppSolution` that contains code from `$/SubFolder/ProjectA/` and `$/SubFolder2/Project1/`, I want to have a separate workspace or something, possibly named "MyAppSolution_Workspace" or something like that, that will map the solution folder and the related project folders to a generic path. This would need to work and be accessible from all other separate computers and would need to keep the same directory structure from the server and have the same folder names and everything as is expected by the solution/project files.

From what it looks like Shared work spaces in VS2010 would work, but it seems to only apply to one machine and is not entirely generic.

Are there any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't like this answer but here is what we do:

Keep your workspace mapping as simple as possible.  Never move folders or rename folders or files using the workspace mapping.  Then all users need to do is map from the top and everything works.  They may get more files than they want but it will work.

Advanced users can use the folder cloaking ability to block getting folders they aren't interested in or can map just the folders they want. The key being that when they map specific folders instead of the root they leave the paths the same as they would be if the root was mapped.

In our system we then have our version and release branching structure above the folders of your example.  So everything you've listed would be duplicated inside a MAIN folder and inside a Release_1 folder.

Comment: I'll also warn you that we ran into trouble trying to use the TFS build system while using projects in multiple solutions.  The GUIDs inside the project files that link the projects together and to TFS can get out of sync when a project is used in multiple solutions.  That isn't a problem for manual builds inside the IDE, but the TFS build agents use the GUIDs to find the dependencies and the build will fail if they get out of sync.

Comment: I talked with my boss and did some research and this is probably what we will do. Thanks for the response.